# Trying to understand iptables rules on the tomato router

Tags: iptables, router

I am working on configuring a linux machine as a router, and I took /etc/iptables file from the tomato router.  I would like to use this file as a starting point for the firewall rules on the linux box.

There are lots of things there that I think I understand, and some thing that I have no clue about and would appreciate some help.  "vlan2" is the external interface, and "br0" is the internal interface.

The first section in the file is

```
    *mangle
    -I PREROUTING -i vlan2 -j DSCP --set-dscp 0
    -I FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
    COMMIT
```

The first line rewrites DSCP bits in the TOS octed in the IP header, I am not sure why.
The second line I do not understand at all.

The next section is

```
    *nat
    -A PREROUTING -d 67.162.98.230 -j WANPREROUTING
    -A PREROUTING -i vlan2 -d 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 -j DROP
    -A WANPREROUTING -p icmp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1
    -A WANPREROUTING -p tcp  --dport 4662 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.12:4662
    -A WANPREROUTING -p udp  --dport 4665 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.12:4665
    -A WANPREROUTING -p udp  --dport 4672 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.12:4672
    -A WANPREROUTING -p tcp  --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.12:22
    -A WANPREROUTING -p udp  --dport 1195 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.12:1195
    -A POSTROUTING  -o vlan2 -j MASQUERADE
    -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -s 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 -d 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1
    COMMIT
```

Lines 2 and 3 sets WANPREROUTING target for anything coming to the external interface, except packets destined to a private network which are dropped.  Next lines set destination for some ports and protocols, to be used for port forwarding.  MASQUERADE line sets up NAT.
I am not sure what the last line before COMMIT does.

I will break the last section into several parts, and insert line numbers in front of the rules.

```
    *filter
    1  -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
    2  -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    3  -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    4  -A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

Lines 1,2 drops incoming packets (to any interface) with invalid states and accepts packets from established connections.  Lines 3, 4 accept everything coming to the loopback and internal interfaces.

```
    5  -A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
    6  -A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
    7  -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Really not sure what the above three lines do, especially the first one (packets forwarded from br0 to br0 ?)

```
    12 -A FORWARD -i vlan2 -j wanin
    13 -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
    14 -A wanin  -p tcp -m tcp -d 192.168.1.12 --dport 4662 -j ACCEPT
    15 -A wanin  -p udp -m udp -d 192.168.1.12 --dport 4665 -j ACCEPT
    16 -A wanin  -p udp -m udp -d 192.168.1.12 --dport 4672 -j ACCEPT
    17 -A wanin  -p tcp -m tcp -d 192.168.1.12 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    18 -A wanin  -p udp -m udp -d 192.168.1.12 --dport 1195 -j ACCEPT
```

Lines 12, 14-18 handle port forwarding.  Not sure about 13, does it mean accept everything routed through br0 interface?

Could you please comment if my assumptions above are correct, and also explain the rules that I could not figure out.  Thank you for reading.